# How to convert mutation event listener to MutationObserver in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, mutation-observers

I have a function:

```
_add : function(o, n, f) {
          if (o.attachEvent)
             o.attachEvent('on' + n, f);
          else if (o.addEventListener)
             o.addEventListener(n, f, false);
          else
             o['on' + n] = f;
},
```

So when I hit save button it's showing me a warning that `Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.` and my add action is not happening. So my question is how can I convert this function to MutationObserver?

Comment: The docs cover the syntax very well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Also note that the code you're using cannot be directly converted to a MutationObserver because you can use valid events with it, eg. click or change, yet it's the mutation events such as DOMsubtreemodified which will cause the issues. You will need to amend the logic used in the latter cases directly, not this `_add` function